# Ubuntu sees external monitor but the external monitor doesn't recieve any signal

Tags: 14.04, drivers, amd-graphics, fglrx, external-monitor

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo B50-70 laptop, with an integrated GPU Intel HD Graphics 4400 along with a dedicated GPU AMD Radeon R5 M230. 
The output for lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3815
Kernel driver in use: i915 

0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3815
```

I want to connect my laptop to an external monitor through HDMI. Ubuntu detects the monitor but no matter what I do, the monitor keeps saying "No DisplayPort Cable". 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3vFP.png

I installed the fglrx driver, but the output for fglrxinfo is:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 10.1.3)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Look at `Xorg.1.log` and `xrandr` what you have

Comment: You many have an "incompatible" cable, a quick internet search was unclear concerning this.  See text following: "If you're looking to connect a computer to a monitor, there's no reason not to use DisplayPort. The cables are roughly the same price as HDMI. The video signal over DVI is basically the same as HDMI. The maximum resolution potential depends on the equipment, though." https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=displayport&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8